# Styling the border inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css, border

What I'm trying to do is to put the border with the custom shape inside articles with different images inside, and I need it to change the shape (and show the paragraph with box caption) while on hover. I've tried some tricks but they didn't work and I'm out of ideas how to make it work. The solution has to be supported by Chrome 17+, Firefox 10+, Safari 5+, Opera 10.5+, IE 9+.
See the picture below for better understanding:
[image]

Do you guys have any ideas on how to make that? Maybe it shouldn't be made by using border? Maybe there is a jQuery solution to do that?
Here's the code: http://codepen.io/tomaff/pen/XMBjKz (It's written with SASS so I'm not sure if I can post it inside a snippet.

```css
@mixin clearfix {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.pictures-section {
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

.pictures-wrapper {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @include clearfix;
  article {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 23%;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: honeydew;
    margin: 0 1%;
    float: left;
    &:before {
      content: "";
      border: 20px solid white;
    }
    &:first-child {
      border-top: 8px solid blue;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      border-top: 8px solid green;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      border-top: 8px solid crimson;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-top: 8px solid yellow;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
      width: 49%;
      height: 220px;
      margin: 0.5% 0.5%;
    }
  }
  img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
      height: initial;
    }
  }
}

#pictures-img1 {
  left: -520px;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
    left: -900px;
    top: -300px;
  }
}

#pictures-img2 {
  left: -320px;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
    top: -45px;
    left: -340px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="pictures-section">
  <div class="pictures-wrapper">
    <article>
      <img src="http://www.sipsala.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Basics-of-Photography-for-Beginners-SipSala-Sri-Lanka.jpg" alt="woman" id="pictures-img1">
      <p>Box caption</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="https://stocklandmartelblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/martin-sigal_nike-6.jpeg" alt="nike campaign photo" id="pictures-img2">
      <p>Box caption</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="http://www.sipsala.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Basics-of-Photography-for-Beginners-SipSala-Sri-Lanka.jpg" alt="woman" id="pictures-img3">
      <p>Box caption</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="https://stocklandmartelblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/martin-sigal_nike-6.jpeg" alt="nike campaign photo" id="pictures-img4">
      <p>Box Caption</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily when you keep the images as a div background. (Preview: http://cssdeck.com/labs/cr9kfykv)

**CSS (style.css):**

```
body {
    background: #cdcdcd;
}

div.pictures-wrapper {
    max-width: 220px;
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article {
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 220px;
    z-index: 5;

}

div.pictures-wrapper article:hover .image-holder  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article:hover > p {
    display: block;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article div.image-holder {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image:url('http://www.sipsala.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Basics-of-Photography-for-Beginners-SipSala-Sri-Lanka.jpg');
}

div.pictures-wrapper article p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px 5px 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<section class="pictures-section">
  <div class="pictures-wrapper">
    <article>
       <div class="image-holder"></div>
       <p>Box caption</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you'll need to add an animations on hover using jquery or other lib as you like.

> **UPDATE:** Without using background image you can use the same tricks with this minor changes

**HTML:**

```
...
    <article>
        <img class="image-holder" src="http://www.sipsala.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Basics-of-Photography-for-Beginners-SipSala-Sri-Lanka.jpg" />
       <p>Box caption</p>
    </article>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #cdcdcd;
}

div.pictures-wrapper {
    max-width: 220px;
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article {
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 220px;
    z-index: 5;

}

div.pictures-wrapper article:hover .image-holder  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article:hover > p {
    display: block;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article img.image-holder {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div.pictures-wrapper article p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px 5px 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

You can find updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/faqotsra/)

Comment: The thing is it unfortunately cannot be done by using div background.

Comment: Why not? its doable. `<div class="image-holder" style="background-image:url('...');">` . Or you seeking for other approach?

Comment: I know its doable, but I'm looking for other approach. The requirement is that I can't use images as background.

Comment: Read **Update** above